# Plotting a SpatialLine in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've done a lot of searching on this topic and have yet to find anything that seems to solve my problem. I am working on plotting a road segment and overlaying some radar data that I have. Below is an example of what I am working on.

[image]

I've generated the above plot with the following ...

```
map <- get_map(
location = c(-86.34, 39.94),
source = "google", zoom = 13, maptype = "roadmap"
)

lon <- c(-86.355750256169358, -86.357100144855735, -86.359359890246708)
lat <- c(39.949089789262416, 39.950209921850444, 39.952050262109935)
roadDf <- data.frame(lon, lat)

ggmap(map) + geom_tile(data = mrms_sub, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = palmer)) + 
geom_point(data = mrms_sub, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
geom_point(data = roadDf, col = "red")
```

I currently have my road segment showing as the three points from my WKT LINESTRING as a means of visualizing it but ultimately I want to show it as a line segment on the map. I've tried using rgeos readWKT function which makes a "Formal class SpatialLine". If I plot it using,

```
plot(roadSegment)
```

it works but I can't make it work with my ggplot. I've tried using geom_lines and geom_segments but it throws the following errors.

```
geom_segment(roadSegment, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude))
#Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

geom_line(line, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude))
#Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`
```

My linestring is the following is read in like so ...

```
#define roads
road1 <-("LINESTRING(-86.355750256169358 39.949089789262416, -86.357100144855735 39.950209921850444, -86.359359890246708 39.952050262109935)")
roadSegment <- rgeos::readWKT(road1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The latest `ggplot2` release can handle `sf` objects. Try with `roadSegment <- sf::st_as_sfc(road1)`

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as I have a chance and let you know, thanks for the help!

Comment: it's the [`geom_sf`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html) function in particular.

Comment: So, I've got ggplot2 loaded through the tidyverse package but for some reason geom_sf is stll not included. I've checked and my ggplot2 version is the latest version. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it isn't released on CRAN yet; try `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`

Comment: If you want an interactive map you could also try `library(leaflet)` and/or `library(googleway)` - the latter is mine and it plots data on a google map